# Taylor expansion to contain sample mean, sample variance, sample skewness, and sample kurtosis

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, mean, skewness, kurtosis

I have the following expression:

$$\frac{1}{p} \ln\left(1+\frac{p^1}{1!n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \frac{p^2}{2!n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + \frac{p^3}{3!n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3 + \frac{p^4}{4!n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^4 + \cdots \right)$$

Now let

$$Y = \frac{p^1}{1!n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \frac{p^2}{2!n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + \frac{p^3}{3!n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3 + \frac{p^4}{4!n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^4 + \cdots$$

Then we have

$$\frac{1}{p}\ln\left(1+Y\right)$$

Using the Taylor series expansion on log, we have

$$\frac{1}{p}\ln(1+Y) = \frac{1}{p}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{Y^n}{n} = \frac{1}{p}\left[Y - \frac{Y^2}{2} + \frac{Y^3}{3} - \frac{Y^4}{4} + \frac{Y^5}{5} - \cdots\right] $$

My question is, how can I expand the above expression so that my final approximation contains the following variables:

Sample mean: $\displaystyle \overline{x} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$

Sample variance: $\displaystyle s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \overline{x})^2 $

Sample skewness: $\displaystyle g_1 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \overline{x})^3}{(n-1)s^3}$

Sample kurtosis: $\displaystyle g_2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \overline{x})^4}{(n-1)s^4}$

---

To illustrate exactly what I mean, I know how to obtain the approximation so that it includes the sample mean and sample variance. Start with the expression as derived above:

$$\frac{1}{p}\left[Y - \frac{Y^2}{2} + \frac{Y^3}{3} - \frac{Y^4}{4} + \frac{Y^5}{5} - \cdots\right]\ \ \ \cdots \ \ (1)$$

Ignore the terms from $\frac{Y^3}{3}$ onwards and substitute in the original expression for $Y$:

$$\frac{1}{p}\left[ \left(\frac{p}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \frac{p^2}{2!n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + \cdots \right) - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{p}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \frac{p^2}{2!n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + \cdots\right)^2 + \cdots \right]$$

$$=\frac{1}{p} \left[\frac{p}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \frac{p^2}{2n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - \frac{p^2}{2n^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^2 + \cdots\right] $$

$$\approx \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \frac{p}{2n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - \frac{p}{2} \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2 $$

$$ = \overline{x} + \frac{p}{2} \left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^2\right]$$

$$= \overline{x} + \frac{p}{2} \left[\frac{n-1}{n} s^2 \right] \ \ \ \cdots \ \ (2)$$

---

As can be seen above, the final approximation contains the sample mean and sample variance. However, I am not sure how exactly I can manipulate the expansion to contain sample skewness and sample kurtosis. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer is so short I hesitate to make it an answer: You do it by writing $m_3=g_1\hat\sigma^3$ and $m_4=g_2\hat\sigma^4$

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I follow. I don't mean manipulation the expression $\overline{x} + \frac{p}{2} \left[\frac{n-1}{n} s^2 \right]$. What I mean is, which terms should I keep from the expansion (instead of dropping them), so that I get a skewness and kurtosis term? E.g., in my example, I used a second order approximation, hence I get the sample mean and sample variance, but I'm having trouble manipulating the third and fourth order approximation to get the required variables.

Comment: Is the difficulty just the relationship between raw and central sample moments?

Comment: @Glen_b Apologies for the late reply, I've been overseas (and still am). The difficulty is I don't know the algebraic manipulations from the equation $\frac{1}{p}\left[Y - \frac{Y^2}{2} + \frac{Y^3}{3} - \frac{Y^4}{4} + \frac{Y^5}{5} - \cdots\right]$ onwards. That is, which terms do I drop and how do I expand things so I am left with all 4 expressions: sample mean, sample variance, sample skewness and sample kurtosis in the final expression.

Comment: You need to manipulate the terms to fourth order.  No 5th powers are involved in any of the expressions you have.

Comment: Yes, so I've tried to keep the terms up to $\frac{Y^4}{4}$ and then substituting back in the expression for $Y$, but I get lost in terms of how many terms should I expand out from the squared term, i.e., $Y^2/2$, how many terms do I expand out for the $Y^3/3$ and $Y^4/4$? Which terms from the expansion do I use? And how do I manipulate everything? Sorry, I just get lost in the algebra because I don't know exactly how to manipulate it...

Comment: This looks like routine bookwork - is this for some subject? Note that your expansions in terms of $x-\bar x$ are analogous to the relationship between raw and central moments -- [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_moment#Relation_to_moments_about_the_origin) and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralMoment.html). If you know how to go between those, you might find it easier to see how to do the sample equivalents. They follow directly from the binomial expansion (and some subsequent simplification and gathering of like terms).

Comment: Actually the original question was just to get the sample mean and sample variance involved in the final expression, but I thought of the extension myself. OK, thank you for the tips, I will try again, and let you know how I go. Thanks.

Comment: Incidentally, when you say "the above expression" ... there are several expressions above the phrase which you might be referring to (at least two). Which of the expressions do you mean? I may have been answering the wrong question

Comment: To avoid confusion, I just edited and labelled them. There are 2 expressions I am dealing with, first is equation (1) (with the expression for $Y$ substituted in). I want to manipulate and approximate equation (1) so that equation (2) contains $\overline{x}$, $s^2$, $g_1$ and $g_2$.

Comment: Sorry about that, I think I see what's going on now; I got confused about what Y was doing for a second.

Comment: Haha no worries, your help is greatly appreciated! I'll have another go :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is more an illustration of something that doesn't quite work (and an explanation of why).

Starting here:

Sample mean: $\displaystyle \overline{x} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$

Sample variance: $\displaystyle s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \overline{x})^2 $

Sample skewness: $\displaystyle g_1 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \overline{x})^3}{(n-1)s^3}$

Sample kurtosis: $\displaystyle g_2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \overline{x})^4}{(n-1)s^4}$

---

Sample third moment: $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \overline{x})^3=s^3 g_1$

Sample fourth moment: $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \overline{x})^4=s^4 g_2$

So if we let $S_k=\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \overline{x})^k$, then we have:

$S_2 = (n-1) s^2\quad\quad\quad\quad(A)$

$S_3 = (n-1) s^3 g_1$

$S_4 = (n-1) s^4 g_2$

Now let $T_k=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^k$. Note that $T_1 = n\bar x$. We can expand as follows:

$T_k=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^k = \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x +\bar x) ^k$

From the binomial expansion of $(a+b)^k$, we have the particular cases:

$(a+b)^2 \;=\; a^2 \,+\, 2 a b^2 \,+\, b^2\,$,
$(a+b)^3 \;=\; a^3 \,+\, 3 a^2b \,+\, 3 a b^2 \,+\, b^3\,$, and
$(a+b)^4 \;=\; a^4 \,+\, 4 a^3b \,+\, 6 a^2 b^2 \,+\, 4 a b^3 \,+\, b^4\,$.

$T_2=\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x +\bar x)^2 = S_2 +2 \bar x\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)+n\bar{x}^2=S_2+0 +n\bar{x}^2=S_2+n\bar{x}^2$

$T_3=\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x +\bar x)^3=S_3+ 3\bar x \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x )^2+3\bar{x}^2\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x )+n\bar{x}^3\\
\quad =S_3+ 3\bar x S_2+0+n\bar{x}^3=S_3+3\bar x . S_2 + n\bar{x}^3$

$T_4=\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x +\bar x)^4\\
\quad =S_4+4\bar x \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)^3+6\bar{x}^2 \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)^2+4\bar{x}^3 \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)+n\bar{x}^4\\
\quad =S_4+4\bar x S_3+6\bar{x}^2 S_2+0+n\bar{x}^4=S_4+4\bar x S_3+6\bar{x}^2 S_2+n\bar{x}^4$

---

Given all that, what do you think about:

$Y = \frac{p^1}{1!n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \frac{p^2}{2!n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + \frac{p^3}{3!n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3 + \frac{p^4}{4!n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^4 + \cdots\\
\quad =\frac{p^1}{1!n}T_1+ \frac{p^2}{2!n} T_2 + \frac{p^3}{3!n} T_3 + \frac{p^4}{4!n} T_4 + \cdots\\$

$\ln(1+Y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{Y^n}{n} = \left[Y - \frac{Y^2}{2} + \frac{Y^3}{3} - \frac{Y^4}{4} + \frac{Y^5}{5} - \cdots\right]$
$\quad = \left[Y - \frac{1}{2}Y^2 + \frac{1}{3}Y^3 - \frac{1}{4}Y^4 + \frac{1}{5}Y^5 - \cdots\right]$

$\quad = \left[(\frac{p^1}{1!n}T_1+ \frac{p^2}{2!n} T_2 + \frac{p^3}{3!n} T_3 + \frac{p^4}{4!n} T_4 + \cdots)\\
 - \frac{1}{2}(\frac{p^1}{1!n}T_1+ \frac{p^2}{2!n} T_2 + \frac{p^3}{3!n} T_3 + \frac{p^4}{4!n} T_4 + \cdots)^2 \\
+ \frac{1}{3}(\frac{p^1}{1!n}T_1+ \frac{p^2}{2!n} T_2 + \frac{p^3}{3!n} T_3 + \frac{p^4}{4!n} T_4 + \cdots)^3 \\
- \frac{1}{4}(\frac{p^1}{1!n}T_1+ \frac{p^2}{2!n} T_2 + \frac{p^3}{3!n} T_3 + \frac{p^4}{4!n} T_4 + \cdots)^4 \\
+ \frac{1}{5}(\frac{p^1}{1!n}T_1+ \frac{p^2}{2!n} T_2 + \frac{p^3}{3!n} T_3 + \frac{p^4}{4!n} T_4 + \cdots)^5 \\
- \cdots\right]$
$\quad = (\frac{p^1}{1!n}T_1\left[1 - \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}- \frac{1}{4}+ \frac{1}{5}\cdots\right]$
$+ \frac{p^2}{2!n} T_2 \left[1 - \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}- \frac{1}{4}+ \frac{1}{5}\cdots\right]$
$+ \frac{p^3}{3!n} T_3 \left[1 - \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}- \frac{1}{4}+ \frac{1}{5}\cdots\right]$
$+ \frac{p^4}{4!n} T_4 \left[1 - \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}- \frac{1}{4}+ \frac{1}{5}\cdots\right]$
$ + \cdots)$

[There's a issue here I'll come back to.]

$\quad = \ln 2 (\frac{p^1}{1!n}T_1+ \frac{p^2}{2!n} T_2 + \frac{p^3}{3!n} T_3 + \frac{p^4}{4!n} T_4 + \cdots)$

$\quad = \ln 2 (\frac{p^1}{1!n}n\bar x+ \frac{p^2}{2!n} (S_2+n\bar{x}^2) + \frac{p^3}{3!n} (S_3+3\bar x . S_2 + n\bar{x}^3) + \frac{p^4}{4!n} (S_4+4\bar x S_3+6\bar{x}^2 S_2+n\bar{x}^4) + \cdots)$

etc (you then substitute the equations at $(A)\,$).

Now to the issue. That change in order of summation is really only legal if the series is absolutely convergent (the alternating harmonic series isn't). So I guess you can't actually do that.

The other thing is that we actually (in spite of me saying otherwise in comments) also need to keep track of the last few terms from the expansion of every higher moment as well (not that this would necessarily prevent us from proceeding), so perhaps this approach isn't fruitful even if there weren't the problem with the alternating harmonic series.

Another approach may be more useful. (When a good answer gets posted I may remove this one.)

Comment: (+1) The sheer hard work behind this alone deserves a (belated) upvote.